# Don't understand "#define for if-statement"

Tags: c++, if-statement

I was looking at a code used to wrapped lua into a C++ application.

I was very surprised to find this:

```
#define for if (false) {} else for
```

I don't understand the meaning of this. To me, it seems useless to do something like that.

Does it have to do something with some compiler tricks or something else ?

PS: The library I was looking at is [luabind](https://github.com/rpavlik/luabind).

Answer (score 6):

I've seen something similar to this to mitigate a compiler bug where the scoped of the for-variable leaked outside of the for-statement.

Related: [/Zc:forScope (Force Conformance in for Loop Scope)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84wcsx8x.aspx).